# How can i get a recipe to calculate font size?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to write a function with the purpose of automatically setting the font size for an element based on its width and the content inside. For example, if my element has a width of 300px, when the width of the content inside is smaller than the element's width, it will use the default font size.

However, when the width of the content inside is larger, it should decrease the font size to fit appropriately. I haven't found the exact formula for this yet.

Any comments from you all are always welcome and contribute ideas. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to know how wide a particular string will be in a particular font until you try rendering it (unless it's a monospaced font).

You can write Javascript to calculate the size of the text in the default font, and then scale it down. I additionally set it to 99% of the scaled-down calculation, to prevent slight overflows from sometimes happening.

```js
function calcFontSize(text, defaultFontSizePx, maxWidth) {
  let div = document.createElement('div')
  div.style.display = 'inline-block'
  div.textContent = text
  div.style.whiteSpace = 'pre'
  div.style.visibility = 'hidden'
  div.style.fontSize = `${defaultFontSizePx}px`
  document.body.appendChild(div)
  let n = defaultFontSizePx
  if(div.clientWidth > maxWidth) 
    n = 0.99 * defaultFontSizePx * maxWidth / div.clientWidth
  div.remove()
  return n
}

function fitTextInsideDiv(text, id) {
  let d = document.getElementById(id)
  d.textContent = text
  d.style.fontSize = `${calcFontSize(text, 14, d.clientWidth)}px`
  console.log(d.style.fontSize)
}

fitTextInsideDiv('hello', 'd1')
fitTextInsideDiv('the quick brown fox', 'd2')
```

```html
<div id="d1" style="width: 100px; background-color:yellow"></div>
<div id="d2" style="width: 100px; background-color:lightblue"></div>
```